# Can you put "than OO" at the end of a sentence when you say "How many times"

Tags: grammar, word-order, questions, comparison

> How many times larger than the moon is the earth?

My textbook says this is the correct answer and doesn't mention about the pattern that you put "than the moon" at the end of the sentence which begins with "How many times".

> How much larger is the earth than the moon?

My textbook also says you can put "than the moon" in the end of the sentence when the sentence begins with "how much larger".

Why can't I put "then the moon" at the end when the sentence starts with "how many times"? or what my textbook says is wrong? I think the first one is a rare pattern though.

Comment: It sounds like your text book (which you do not name) is limited. Does it actually say that the 'than the...' form is wrong, or just doesn't mention it?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey my textbook said, "if you use 'how much', you can put than clause in the end." They actually don't mention about the word order of the "how many times" pattern, but it implied that you can't put the than clause in the end when you use "how many times"

Answer (score -1):

Both could be correct, but they are asking different things and would elicit different answers.

There are things that are *countable*, and there are things that are *measurable*, for example:

- How *much* water is there?
- How *many* people are there?

People can be *counted*, water can be *measured*.

In your example, the size of the moon and size of the earth have already been measured and established in numerical terms. Asking "how many *times* more/less" is asking someone to count the 'times'.

> Q. How many times larger than the moon is the earth?
> A. It is 4 times larger

Asking 'how much larger' one is than the other invites the difference to be *measured*. That could be expressed as a measurement in the original metric, or as a percentage:

> Q. How *much* larger than the moon is the earth?
> A. It is 400% larger.

Comment: I know that the nuances are different. I'm sorry if my English sounds odd, but I'm asking about word order.

Comment: @ra1ned if you understand the difference, look at my examples and see the word order I applied.